# How to get the differences of two similar javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm making a node.js game that uses socket.io. Instead of constantly sending the positions of all players in the game, I only want to send the updated positions of the players to decrease the amount of lag.

I've been thinking about this for a long time, but I still haven't figured out how to do it.

```
var oldPositions = {x: 10, y: 50};
var newPosotions = {x: 10, y: 20};

var positionUpdate = myFunction(oldPositions, newPositions);

//so positionUpdate should equal {y: 20}
```

I want to create a function which would return

```
{y: 20}
```

based on my example code.

Comment: How would you compare lists of names and values written on two pieces of paper without using a computer at all?

Comment: Do you know how loops over objects work?

Comment: No, I don't know how loops over objects work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Get the entries of the `newPositions` using `Object.entries`.
- `filter()` the entries to remove those entries for which value is same for both object.
- Convert entries to object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
var oldPositions = {x: 10, y: 50};
var newPositions = {x: 10, y: 20};

const myFunction = (a,b) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(b).filter(([k,v]) => v !== a[k])) 

var positionUpdate = myFunction(oldPositions, newPositions);
console.log(positionUpdate)
```

> what does the k, v mean?

The `k` means the current key through which we are iterating and `v` for the corresponding value. This for the second object.

Actually the entries of array looks like

```
[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]...]
```

Now when we apply `filter()` on entries each element be an array `[key, value]`. The code is using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I just have a question so I can understand the logic: what does the k, v mean?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. In {name: "Jim"} the key would be "name" and the value would be "Jim"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var oldPositions = {x: 10, y: 50};
var newPositions = {x: 10, y: 20}

const positionUpdate = (oldPositions, newPositions) =>
       Object.keys(newPositions)
         .filter(key => oldPositions[key] !== newPositions[key])
         .reduce((acc, ele) => (acc[ele] = newPositions[ele], acc),{});

console.log(positionUpdate(oldPositions, newPositions))
```

Answer (score 0):

define the function like this:

```
function myFunction(oldPosition, newPosition){
   if(oldPosition.x != newPosition.x){
     newX = oldPosition.x - newPosition.x; //if negative just transform in positive 
   }else{
     newX = newPosition.x;
  }
   if(oldPosition.y != newPosition.y){
     newY = oldPosition.y - newPosition.y; //if negative just transform in positive 
   }else{
     newY = newPosition.y;
  }
  movement= {
             x=newX,
             y=newY
            };

 return movement;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I want a function to have a loop so I don't have to manually add more else ifs